# What is the most efficient Ruby data structure to track progress?

Tags: ruby, performance, data-structures

I am working on a small project which progressively grows a list of links and then processes them through a queue. There exists the likelihood that a link may be entered into the queue twice and I would like to track my progress so I can skip anything that has already been processed. I'm estimating around 10k unique links at most.

For larger projects I would use a database but that seems overkill for the amount of data I am working with and would prefer some form of in-memory solution that can potentially be serialized if I want to save progress across runs.

What data structure would best fit this need?

**Update:** I am already using a hash to track which links I have completed processing. Is this the most efficient way of doing it?

```
def process_link(link)
  return if @processed_links[link]
  # ... processing logic
  @processed_links[link] = Time.now # or other state
end
```

Comment: Use a Hash or a Set. You can only have a single instance of a key in a Hash. A Set is built upon Hash keys and so you get a similar behavior.

Comment: Another thing to think of, do you have to track progress over outages/crashes/restarts? If so, you can't use an in-memory tracking at all and probably should use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't concerned about memory, then just use a Hash to check inclusion; insert and lookup times are O(1) average case. Serialization is straightforward (Ruby's Marshal class should take care of that for you, or you could use a format like JSON). Ruby's `Set` is an array-like object that is backed with a Hash, so you could just use that if you're so inclined.

However, if memory is a concern, then this is a great problem for a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)! You can achieve set inclusion testing in constant time and the filter uses substantially less memory than a hash would. The tradeoff is the Bloom filters are probabilistic - you can get false inclusion positives. You can eliminate the probability of most false positives with the right bloom filter parameters, but if duplicates are the exception rather than the rule, you could implement something like:

1. Check for set inclusion in the Bloom filter [O(1)]
2. If the bloom filter reports that the entry is found, perform an O(n) check of the input data, to see if this item has been found in the array of input data prior to now.

That would get you very fast and memory-efficient lookups for the common case, and you could make the choice to accept the possibility of false negatives (to keep the whole thing small and fast), or you could perform verification of set inclusion when a duplicate is reported (to only do expensive work when you absolutely have to).

https://github.com/igrigorik/bloomfilter-rb is a Bloom filter implementation I've used in the past; it works nicely. There are also redis-backed Bloom filters, if you need something that can perform set membership tracking and testing across multiple app instances.

Comment: Thank you, this is just the information I was looking for. I had not considered a Bloom filter as the usual case is guaranteed not there, potential false positive for checking inclusion. That addition of the O(n) check when you get a hit is a nice lightweight addition.

Answer (score 1):

How about a Set and convert your links to value object (rather than reference object) like Structs.  By creating a value object the Set will be able to detect its uniqueness.  Alternately, you could use a hash and store links by their PK.

Comment: A `Hash` did seem the most obvious but I'm not sure how well the key hashing would hold up over 10k inserts, both memory and processing wise.

Comment: The key hashing will be fine. A better question is how will Ruby handle 10K keys and associated values? Perhaps a decent backend database would be better?

Comment: Running an early version of my script ended up yielding many more links than expected. When I hit 300k in the `Queue` object, and using a `Hash` object to track all links seen, I decided it was time to use a DB to track across runs and crashes. Additionally, I was pleasantly surprised that the Ruby process was only using about 15MB of RAM and there was barely a blip on my CPU (most of the time was spent locking on the network).

Answer (score 1):

The data structure could be a hash:

```
current_status = { links: [link3, link4, link5], processed: [link1, link2, link3] }
```

To track your progress (in percent):

```
links_count = current_status[:links].length + current_status[:processed].length
progress = (current_status[:processed].length * 100) / links_count # Will give you percent of progress
```

To process your links:

- `push` any new link you need to process to `current_status[:links]`.
- Use `shift` to take from `current_status[:links]` the next link to be processed.
- After processing a link, `push` it to `current_status[:processed]`

**EDIT**

As I see it (and understand your question), the logic to process your links would be:

```
# Add any new link that needs to be processed to the queue unless it have been processed
def add_link_to_queue(link)
  current_status[:to_process].push(link) unless current_status[:processed].include?(link)
end

# Process next link on the queue
def process_next_link
  link = current_status[:to_process].shift # return first link on the queue
  # ... login process the link
  current_status[:processed].push(link)
end

# shift method will not only return but also remove the link from the original array to avoid duplications
```

Comment: Using both links and processed, I would need to check the existence of the link in two arrays, each one through an `#include?` which, I believe, is implemented as a simple scan operation. Processing time would add up quickly as I started adding lots of links to each of those arrays.

Comment: Also, I'm already using a `Queue` to handle the actual processing portion. I'm just looking for an efficient way of tracking which entries I have completed so I do not process them again if they got put back in the queue.

Comment: @SethV I just edited my answer. As I see it, you only need to check the existance in one array (array of processed links). Check it out and tell me, maybe i'm not understanding well what you want.